# JAXB : Please verify the structure for the XML to java in JAXB

Tags: jaxb

This is my XML file

```
   <BADFM>
<Given>
<Ord>
<Bag IDC="DM" />
</Ord>
</Given>
</BADFM>
```

This is my Parser class

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        File file = new File("D:\\BADML.xml");
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext
                .newInstance(MyMessage.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        MyMessage authentifyResult = (MyMessage) jaxbUnmarshaller
                .unmarshal(file);
        System.out.println(authentifyResult.getGiven().getOrd().getBag().getIDC());

    }
}
```

This is MyMessage

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="BADFM")
public class MyMessage
{
@XmlElement(name="Given")
private Given given;

public Given getGiven() {
    return given;
}

public void setGiven(Given given) {
    this.given = given;
}


}
```

This is Given.java

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

public class Given {
    private Ord ord;
    @XmlElement(name = "Ord")
    public Ord getOrd() {
        return ord;
    }
    public void setOrd(Ord ord) {
        this.ord = ord;
    }
}
```

This is Ord.java

```
 import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

public class Ord {

    private Bag bag;
    @XmlElement(name="Bag")
    public Bag getBag() {
        return bag;
    }

    public void setBag(Bag bag) {
        this.bag = bag;
    }

}
```

**This is Bag.java**

```
  import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;

public class Bag {
      @XmlAttribute(name="IDC")
    private String IDC ;

    public String getIDC() {
        return IDC;
    }
    @XmlAttribute(name="IDC")
    public void setIDC(String IDC) {
        IDC = IDC;
    }

}
```

When i ran that i am getting

```
  Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Class has two properties of the same name "IDC"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String Bag.getIDC()
        at Bag
        at public Bag Ord.getBag()
        at Ord
        at public Ord Given.getOrd()
        at Given
        at public Given MyMessage.getGiven()
        at MyMessage
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.lang.String Bag.IDC
        at Bag
        at public Bag Ord.getBag()
        at Ord
        at public Ord Given.getOrd()
        at Given
        at public Given MyMessage.getGiven()
        at MyMessage

    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at Test.main(Test.java:11)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `@XmlAttribute` for the `IDC` variable of the `Bag` class. Once you make that change, the XML you referenced at the top will work.

As for your current code, it is expecting the XML to look like:

```
<Bag>
  <IDC>DM</IDC>
</Bag>
```

You can easily see what type of XML your classes are expecting by populating all attribute fields and then marshaling the object to a file.

**Update**

You should always declare your attributes as private if you are going to have properly named getters and setters. Otherwise, JAXB will throw the error `Class has two properties of the same name`.

When declaring that a class attribute is a `@XmlAttribute`, you should also put the annotation on the getter so that JAXB does not think you want both a `@XmlAttribute` and `@XmlElement` with the same name.

```
public class Bag {
    private String IDC ;

    @XmlAttribute(name="IDC")
    public String getIDC() {
        return IDC;
    }

    public void setIDC(String IDC) {
        this.IDC = IDC;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , so if i use the @XmlAttribute for the IDC will the  code will work for the this XML <BADFM>
<Given>
<Ord>
<Bag IDC="DM" />
</Ord>
</Given>
</BADFM>

Comment: Hi ,Thanks for the prompt response , When i ran that , i am getting  2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions , i have updated my question , please tell me what is wrong

Comment: Fixed the answer to account for your new issues.

Comment: I changed the access specifier from Protected to private inside MyMessage.java , but could you please tell me ", you should also put the annotation on the getter" in which  where exactly i exactly need to put this ? i have updated my question also

Comment: Now there is no exception , but the value is null , when i tried to access using System.out.println(authentifyResult.getGiven().getOrd().getBag().getIDC());

Comment: What does the XML look like when you marshal a AuthentifyResult with IDC populated?

Comment: <BADFM>
<Given>
<Ord>
<Bag IDC="DM" />
</Ord>
</Given>
</BADFM>

Comment: You have a typo in your setIDC function. I fixed it in my example code.

Comment: I ran that , and it is working fine , thanks a lot you took care as it is your work . Have a nice day .